# MySQL: Formatting a string

Tags: mysql, string

My database contains a string pattern that is used to allow for easy user editing via a JS-script.

The string is basicly formatted like so:

```
aaa[bbb#ccc]ddd[eee#fff]ggg
```

the result I am looking for is

```
aaacccdddfffggg
```

I'd like to do this when selecting the string from the database. I'm guessing a regex should do the trick. But my knowledge in the subject of regex's is rather limited. However, this is not a requirement, if there exist a more elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only use a [MySQL REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) in a WHERE clause, to match against values. You can't use them to transform Strings.

You'll either need to do it clientside, or work with the other [String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html). A `MID()` would do the trick, if the lengths and positions of the substrings are fixed. If not, use `POSITION()` (or `LOCATE()`) to find the special characters `[]#`.

Comment: Hehe, yeah! I see your point. I was not thinking straight. Regex's are not in any way related. My bad. :) I'll give it a try using POSITION().

Comment: @dotmartin: no actually regexes would be the way to go if the format is jumpy - any decent programmer would think about using those, so you were thinking straight :). It's just that MySQL can only use them to match, so you'd need a clientside regexp in your Perl/PHP/Rails/... code.